# Wallpaper manager, getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent error

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I am trying to use getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent for cropping and saving image as wallpaper. but i am getting error "getImageUri (Bitmap, Context)in Utils cannot be applied to (Bitmap)".

Here is the code

```
public void setAsWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) {

    WallpaperManager imageView = null;
    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    WallpaperManager wm
            = WallpaperManager.getInstance(_context);

    try {
        new Intent(wm.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(getImageUri(bitmap))); (**ERROR IS ON THIS LINE**)
        Toast.makeText(_context,
                _context.getString(R.string.toast_wallpaper_set),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(_context,
                _context.getString(R.string.toast_wallpaper_set_failed),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private Uri getImageUri(Bitmap inImage, Context inContext) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(),
            inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

And this is logcat.

```
Process: com.example.wallpaper, PID: 25187

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.app.WallpaperManager.getDrawable()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.wallpaper.util.Utils.setAsWallpaper(Utils.java:90)
                                                                                   at com.example.wallpaper.FullScreenViewActivity.onClick(FullScreenViewActivity.java:267)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

NEW ERROR LOG

```
E/MediaStore: Failed to insert image
                                                                           java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=11235, uid=10207 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                                               at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                               at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                               at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
                                                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1284)
                                                                               at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:986)
                                                                               at com.builditpossible.wallpaperpack.util.Utils.getImageUri(Utils.java:107)
                                                                               at com.builditpossible.wallpaperpack.util.Utils.setAsWallpaper(Utils.java:93)
                                                                               at com.builditpossible.wallpaperpack.FullScreenViewActivity.onClick(FullScreenViewActivity.java:259)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

SET WALLPAPER AND DOWNLOAD BUTTON

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
            .getBitmap();
    switch (v.getId()) {
    // button Download Wallpaper tapped
    case R.id.llDownloadWallpaper:
        utils.saveImageToSDCard(bitmap);
        break;
    // button Set As Wallpaper tapped
    case R.id.llSetWallpaper:
        utils.setAsWallpaper(bitmap);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NullPointerException` occurs because your `imageView` variable is **null** and you are trying call `getDrawable()` on it.

```
WallpaperManager imageView = null;
bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Also change below line

```
new Intent(wm.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(getImageUri(bitmap))); (**ERROR IS ON THIS LINE**)
```

to

```
new Intent(wm.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(getImageUri(bitmap,_context)));
```

**Update:**

You can get wallpaper as `Drawable` using below code and save it to sdcard.

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

Comment: Can you please edit that for me? I am not friendly with android.

Comment: I think you don't need above two lines. Because you already passing `bitmap` in function parameter. So, remove this two lines and check.

Comment: I have removed them, but "new Intent(wm.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(getImageUri(bitmap)));" is still showing error (the error is on bitmap in the brackets in the end of the line) . it ask me to create getImageUri method even when i have it.

Comment: Yes, you need to pass context as second parameter of method as `getImageUri(bitmap, _context)`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: E/MediaStore: Failed to insert image
                                                                               java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=11235, uid=10207 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission() and soo... Check question for full error.

Comment: Sorry, there was no permission given to app. After i changed that, app is not setting the image as wallpaper, It just toasts that wallpaper changed, and there is no error.

Comment: What is your ImageUri? is it file path or content uri?

Comment: That error is solved, Now set wallpaper button downloads the image insted of setting it as wallpaper.

Comment: This is the code for both buttons, check the question.

Comment: do you mean save wallpaper image to sdcard ?

Comment: i want to do both, one button should set image as wallpaper and other show save it to sd card

Comment: I can save it to sd card, but i am not able to set it as wallpaper. It was working before i put _context in the method.